# ¿Como hacer un POST en Java pasandole un JSON en el body?

Tags: java, post, http

Estoy intentando de hacer un POST a un servidor desde mi aplicación Java pero la respuesta que obtengo es un "400" - Bad client Request. Algo estoy haciendo mal.

Les dejo mi código a ver si me pueden ayudar:

```
package web.hpi;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class JavaPostRequest {

    private static HttpURLConnection con;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException,
        ProtocolException, IOException {

        String url = "http://***.**.20.10:12**0/search";
        String body = "{\\r\\n\\t\\\"token\\\": \\\"1\\\",\\r\\n\\t\\\"query\\\": [{\\r\\n\\t\\t\\\"index\\\": \\\"ALTC.MC_ROBERTS\\\",\\r\\n\\t\\t\\\"terms\\\": [{\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"name\\\": \\\"INDEXTEXT01T\\\",\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"value\\\": \\\"3044071*\\\",\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"operator\\\": \\\"like\\\"\\r\\n\\t\\t}],\\r\\n\\t\\t\\\"results\\\": {\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"count\\\": 5000,\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"sort\\\": [{\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"name\\\": \\\"ISSUE_DATE\\\",\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"order\\\": \\\"descending\\\"\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t}],\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"fields\\\": []\\r\\n\\t\\t}\\r\\n\\t}]\\r\\n}";
        byte[] postData = body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        try {

            URL myurl = new URL(url);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();

            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Java client");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
                wr.write(postData);
            }

            StringBuilder content;

            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {

                String line;
                content = new StringBuilder();

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(line);
                    content.append(System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }

            System.out.println(content.toString());

        } finally {

            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

No estoy usando ninguna librería, solo Java 1.8 standard !
Desde ya muchas gracias a todos !

Comment: Yo suelo usar Apache HttpClient y va bien. En todo caso, suele ser útil usar un *sniffer* como Wireshark para ver qué se está transmitiendo realmente y comparar con ejemplos.

Comment: No se porque no me reconoce los imports el HttpClient de Apache, eso que lo bajé de la página oficial ... me estoy volviendo loco con algo muy facil :(

Comment: Has probado a limpiar el JSON? Todos esos retornos de carro y tabulaciones son innecesarias, así como escapar las comillas tantas veces

Comment: El Json lo parsie con un conversor online de Json a String ... así como lo escupió el conversor lo copie y pegue .... como lo limpio ?? Necesito escapar las comillas si o si para convertirlo a String .. de ahí la idea de conversor

Comment: {"token": "1","query": [{"index": "ALTC.MC_ROBERTS","terms": [{"name": "INDEXTEXT01T","value": "3044071*","operator": "like"}],"results": {"count":5000,"sort": [{"name": "ISSUE_DATE","order": "descending"}],"fields": []}}  Este sería mi Json original

Comment: "Escapas" demasiado; `"` escapado es `\"`. Tú tienes por ejemplo `\\\"token\\\"`, que se corresponde con `\"token\"` (un *string* de 9 caracteres), no con `"token"` (un *string* de 7 caracteres, y el que quieres usar). La "prueba del nueve" es sencillamente imprimir tu *string* por pantalla.

Comment: Ok, voy a borrar un par de escapes, pero no creo que ese sea el problema principal ... igualmente muchas gracias por el consejo